# Retornar código do dado cadastrado logo após o INSERT

Tags: delphi, firebird

eu sei que com java da para fazer, mas não achei nada para fazer isso no delphi(caso possível), sempre que e cadastro um novo item eu busco o código pelo SELECT MAX('CAMPO'), mas gostaria de saber se é possível retornar o código logo após o INSERT:

Exemplo Java:

```
public int inserirOperacao(Pedido pedido){
        try{
            conn = ConectaMySql.obtemConexao();
            String insereOperacao = "INSERT INTO PEDIDO VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, 'P', 'A')";

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insereOperacao, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setInt(1, pedido.getLogCodigo());
            stmt.setString(2, pedido.getPedObservacao());
            stmt.setString(3, pedido.getPedEndereco());

            int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate();

            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            try(ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()){
                if(generatedKeys.next()){
                    return (int) generatedKeys.getLong(1);
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally {
            try {
                if(stmt != null){
                    stmt.close();
                }
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso na própria inserção:

```
insert into TABELA default values
  returning VALOR_QUE_DESEJO_RETORNAR
```

Assim seu insert retornara o valor que você inseriu no campo citado.

Fonte: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-insert.html

Comment: Só não estou entendendo como q eu jogo o valor retornado pra dentro de uma variável õ.õ

seria:

insert into TABELA default values
  returning VALOR_QUE_DESEJO_RETORNAR INTO VARIAVEL?

Comment: Coloca o trecho do codigo em dephi que ta usando para fazer a consulta que tento ajudar.

Comment: por exemplo: insert into PRODUTO (DESCRICAO, PRECO) values ('CHOCOLATE', '7.50');

Comment: Qual o campo que quer que o insert retorne? da tabela digo.

Comment: o codigo do produto que é gerado por auto increment

Comment: Não tem problema, qual o nome do campo na tabela?

Comment: nome do campo é CODIGO

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66670/discussion-between-luiz-santos-and-taha-tsu).

Comment: @LuizSantos Interessante o uso de returning na FDQuery para o Firebird +1

Comment: Valeu :)  @Paz Acho que fica sendo uma boa solução